# Jquery plugin does not work in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

The jquery roundabout plugin works amazing in all browers for me, just not in Firefox and IE. I have the latest versions of the browers and the latest version of the plugin. All other jquery plugins work without a problem and javascript is enabled as well.

Here is the code which opens the roundabout plugin in all browers but firefox and internet explorer after the cllick of a button:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// Start round about action.
$('ul').roundabout({
shape: "waterWheel"
});

// Hide and show on click.
  $('#menuButton').click(function() {
    $('#roundabout-container').stop().toggle(800);
  });
});
```

Help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code inside a document ready: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately that does not help. I used the window.load function because otherwise the roundabout opens up collapsed. Now i used document.ready but that does not change anything.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle and I will see.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kampfkuchen/qU45h/6/ Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You have to link to the Github's raw and not the page my friend. Anyway I took some time to fix it, and it runs well on most browsers, the Plugin seems to have a Problem with jQuery 1.10.x and IE so I switched to jQuery 2.1.0.

Don't forget to vote up: http://jsfiddle.net/qU45h/8/